# Extra Bin with Pandas Resample

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, grouping, resampling

I've got a pandas data frame defined like this:

```
    last_4_weeks_range = pandas.date_range(                                
            start=datetime.datetime(2001, 5, 4), periods=28)               
    last_4_weeks = pandas.DataFrame(                                       
        [{'REST_KEY': 1, 'DLY_TRN_QT': 80, 'DLY_SLS_AMT': 90,              
            'COOP_DLY_TRN_QT': 30, 'COOP_DLY_SLS_AMT': 20}] * 28 +         
        [{'REST_KEY': 2, 'DLY_TRN_QT': 70, 'DLY_SLS_AMT': 10,              
            'COOP_DLY_TRN_QT': 50, 'COOP_DLY_SLS_AMT': 20}] * 28,          
        index=last_4_weeks_range.append(last_4_weeks_range))               
    last_4_weeks.sort(inplace=True)
```

and when I go to resample it:

```
In [265]: last_4_weeks.resample('7D', how='sum')
Out[265]: 
            COOP_DLY_SLS_AMT  COOP_DLY_TRN_QT  DLY_SLS_AMT  DLY_TRN_QT  REST_KEY
2001-05-04               280              560          700        1050        21
2001-05-11               280              560          700        1050        21
2001-05-18               280              560          700        1050        21
2001-05-25               280              560          700        1050        21
2001-06-01                 0                0            0           0         0
```

I end up with an extra empty bin I wouldn't expect to see -- 2001-06-01.  I wouldn't expect that bin to be there, as my 28 days are evenly divisible into the 7 day resample I'm performing.  I've tried messing around with the closed kwarg, but I can't escape that extra bin.  Why is that extra bin showing up when I've got nothing to put into it and how can I avoid generating it?

What I'm ultimately trying to do is get 7 day averages per REST_KEY, so doing a

```
In [266]: last_4_weeks.groupby('REST_KEY').resample('7D', how='sum').mean(level=0)
Out[266]: 
          COOP_DLY_SLS_AMT  COOP_DLY_TRN_QT  DLY_SLS_AMT  DLY_TRN_QT  REST_KEY
REST_KEY                                                                      
1                      112              168          504         448       5.6
2                      112              280           56         392      11.2
```

but that extra empty bin is throwing off my mean (e.g. for COOP_DLY_SLS_AMT I've got 112, which is (20 * 7 * 4) / 5 rather than the 140 I'd get from (20 * 7 * 4) / 4 if I didn't have that extra bin.)  I also wouldn't expect REST_KEY to show up in the aggregation since it's part of the groupby, but that's really a smaller problem.

P.S. I'm using pandas 0.11.0

Comment: A quick fix is to just take only the first 4 elements `[0:4]` but...

Comment: Its very strange. If i count instead of sum i dont end up with the extra bin. (in 0.11)

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a bug:

The output with pandas 0.9.0dev on mac is:

```
In [3]: pandas.__version__
Out[3]: '0.9.0.dev-1e68fd9'


In [6]: last_4_weeks.resample('7D', how='sum')
Out[6]: 
            COOP_DLY_SLS_AMT  COOP_DLY_TRN_QT  DLY_SLS_AMT  DLY_TRN_QT  REST_KEY
2001-05-04                40               80          100         150         3
2001-05-11               280              560          700        1050        21
2001-05-18               280              560          700        1050        21
2001-05-25               280              560          700        1050        21
2001-06-01               240              480          600         900        18


In [4]: last_4_weeks.groupby('REST_KEY').resample('7D', how='sum').mean(level=0)
Out[4]: 
          COOP_DLY_SLS_AMT  COOP_DLY_TRN_QT  DLY_SLS_AMT  DLY_TRN_QT  REST_KEY
REST_KEY                                                                      
1                      112              168          504         448       5.6
2                      112              280           56         392      11.2
```

I'm using this versions (via pip freeze):

```
numpy==1.8.0.dev-9597b1f-20120920
pandas==0.9.0.dev-1e68fd9-20120920
```

Comment: No, your output is just from having closed='right', which I believe used to be the default in pandas.  The default is now closed='left', which is what I want in this situation.  If I do closed='right' in pandas 0.11.0 I get that same output.  You'll notice that your means also have the exact same problem I reported in my original question, which come from the extra bin.  Your bin just happens to occur at a different place (2001-05-04) and is non-empty because you've grabbed a value that would come in a different bin if the interval was closed differently (2001-06-01 is 40 less.)